# Symfony doctrine lazy load properties

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have an entity that stores large files as blobs to the DB.

I would now like to get Symfony to never ever load these blobs unless I specifically request them via the appropriate getter.

In essence I want the same idea as lazy-loading relationships but for a string property.

What I have tried so far is to put all my other properties that hold the file meta data into a trait and then apply that trait to two entities.

```
namespace App\Entity\Traits;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait DocumentMetaData
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date_uploaded;
}
```

One entity has nothing to it but the trait...

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\DocumentMetaData;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Document
{
    use DocumentMetaData;
}
```

...the other has the added blob property:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\DocumentMetaData;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class DocumentFile
{
    use DocumentMetaData;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
     */
    private $blob;
}
```

Now, if I don't want the blob to be loaded, for example for a listing of files, I simply use the entity that doesn't have the blob.

This approach sort of works but causes issues as I need to point both entities at the same table (see the class level ORM annotations).

Specifically, it makes doctrine freak out when running migrations:

> The table with name 'myapp.documents' already exists.

That makes perfect sense and really I'm hoping that someone can point me to a nicer solution.

How can I tell doctrine not to load the blob unless its explicitly asked for?

Comment: Move the blob into it's very own table/entity.  Or don't use the ORM.

Comment: I don't think not using the ORM is an option in my case but the new table approach sounds interesting. Could you elaborate @Cerad ? I assume you mean to have it stored as a One to One relationship instead of directly on the main Entity?

Comment: Nothing mysterious.  Make yourself a DocumentMetaData entity with an id property as well as a blob property.  Then associate it with your Document entity.  You can even explicitly set LAZY_LOAD on the associations just to make sure how it is loaded even though lazy loading will be used by default.  It is all in the docs.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Cerad . If you want to add an answer I'm more than happy to tick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as per the comments on my question - the way to do this so that migrations do not break is to leverage doctrine's ability to lazy load relationships between tables.

Basically I had to go and create a new entity that only holds my giant blobs and then establish a one to one relationship between the original entity and the blob entity.

I then set that relationship to load [EXTRA_LAZY](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) and as a result I can now control when precisely the blobs of giant data should be loaded.

I don't think this is ideal in terms of normalising the DB design but it works a lot better than anything else so happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against storing files in your database. Put them on the file system where they belong and configure your web server / application to (statically) serve them. You can still put your desired methods of authentication / authorization in front, if required.
This also allows you to make use of streaming / reading only as much as you need, without loading the entire file from your DB into RAM.